# AngularJS test a directive with replace set to true

Tags: angularjs, unit-testing, angularjs-directive

My `<custom-directive>` has `replace:true` and `template: '<img />'`.
How can I write a unit test for it? I think I want to test that it actually replaces custom-directive with img.

```
it('should be transformed to <img>', function(){
  var elm = $compile('<custom-directive></custom-directive>')(scope);
  scope.$digest();

  var t = elm.find('img'); // wrong! it replaces the element. it won't find another one inside
 //expect(elm).toBeAnImgElement ?
});
```

I can't find the correct matcher.
The closest case I've seen is checking the contents (`elm.html()` or `elm.text()`) but my tag is empty.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

wrap your directive in a div like:

```
describe('Directive: custom', function () {
  beforeEach(module('App'));

  var element, $scope;

  it('should be transformed to <img>', inject(function ($rootScope, $compile) {
    $scope = $rootScope.$new();
    element = angular.element('<div><custom-directive></custom-directive></div>');
    element = $compile(element)($scope);

    expect(element.children('img').length).toBe(1);
  }));
});
```

Comment: Why do we need `$rootScope.$digest();` here? Indeed, it doesn't work without it, but I don't get why.

Comment: @thorn: Yeah, it's not required.

Comment: For me, it's working without it. Having $digest() does not make sense in this case but If your directive is dependent on the $scope then you have to.

Comment: Do the same thing for testing a transclude directive.

Comment: Thank you, thank you, thank you. This was vexing me.

Answer (score 3):

You can get the actual HTMLElement object and check its tagname. Get at the actual HTMLElement with `elm[0]`:

```
expect(elm[0].tagName).toEqual('A');
```